# XSL-FO Antenna House Formatter - prevent hyphenation across page break

Tags: xsl-fo, antenna-house

With XSL-FO is there a way to prevent words from being hyphenated across a page break whilst hyphenation in general is turned on? I am using Antenna House Formatter. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, no, I don't know of a property to control hyphenation at a page break differently from other hyphenation.

You could use the Area Tree XML output to find the pages that end on a hyphen, find the corresponding word in the FO, modify the FO to either cause a break before the word or stop the word from breaking, and then repeat the process until there are no hyphens at page breaks.

---

Now I do know: use `hyphenation-keep="page"` to stop words being hyphenated across a page break.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#hyphenation-keep.

Comment: a very belated many thanks for this. Will be useful to know for the future.